# Delphi, PGDac vs Zeos, Fetch, Lookup?

Tags: performance, delphi, postgresql, lookup, fetch

I used Zeos to test to know: is ZTable uses fetch technics, or not?

May in the future we migrate our lesser system to PGSQL, and this used now "Table" components (as BDE, but it have an SQL-like server).

These tables use real cursors, a "Window" with N record, so lookup is very fast, because the Locate/Lookup is started on server, and only these N records are refreshed, no matter, how many records in the lookup table.

PGSQL uses fetch technics as I know, and I tested it with a table (id int, name varchar(100)), and 1 million records. (I also trying this with mysql). The adapter is Zeos.

ID, sec to find, allocated memory in bytes on client.

```
MySQL
500000  2,761   113 196 344
1000000 3,214   225 471 232
313800  0,437   225 471 232
328066  0,468   225 471 232
276374  0,390   225 471 232
905984  1,264   225 471 232
260253  0,359   225 471 232

PGSQL
500000  3,042   113 188 184
1000000 3,744   225 463 064
313800  0,436   225 463 064
328066  0,452   225 463 064
276374  0,375   225 463 064
905984  1,295   225 463 064
260253  0,359   225 463 064
142023  0,203   225 463 064
```

As you see the records are fetched locally, this cause the 225 MB usage, and searches are slow a little, based where is the record we must find.

I want to ask more things:

a.)
Is PGDAC have some technics to we can use the lookups without pay the fetch with memory and secs?

b.)
Or is PG ODBC driver can help in this problem with ADO? (As I know ADO can use server side cursors)?

c.)
Have anybody some experience with lookup tables, and performance? Is this critical question or it is not?
(With client memory usage too).

d.)
If no chance to avoid fetch hell with lookups, what we can do?
Server Side Joins, and unique code for Lookup field changing without real Lookup?

Thanks for your help:
   dd

Comment: I use postgres for all my projects except one(in which I use Nexus...), I've used PgDac a year ago or so and I was not happy with the performance, I use UniDac(it's not free, but worths every penny) and I am very happy with them, fast, reliable. I cannot tell you the difference in speed between PgDac and UniDac because I've switched PC(more than double computing power) and I always try to optimize my queries as much as possible, however when the change was made from PgDac to UniDac I haven't got any complains regarding speed, on the contrary, I also made a lot of improvements...

Comment: UniDac does NOT require additional libraries(*.dll) to access a postgre database(this is pretty important)

Comment: UniDAC cannot be faster than PgDAC, because both are sharing the same technology, only exception when UniDAC version is different from PgDAC :)

Comment: But the question is remaining: is there any server-kind cursor or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers answered me:

> Hello,
>
> Now PgDAC can't use server-side cursor
>   as you want. We will investigate the
>   possibility of adding this feature in
>   one of the next builds/versions of
>   PgDAC.
>
> Best regards,  Alex Devart Team
>   www.devart.com

So there is not SS cursor now.

Thanks: 
  dd